# C++ Multiple Inheritance Memory Layout with "Empty classes"

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, memory-alignment

I know the memory layout of multiple inheritance is not defined, so I should not rely on it. However, can I rely on it in a special case. That is, a class has only one "real" super class. All others are "empty classes", i.e., classes that neither have fields nor virtual methods (i.e. they only have non-virtual methods). In this case, these additional classes should not add anything to the memory layout of the class. (More concisely, in the C++11 wording, the class has *standard-layout*)

Can I infer that all the superclasses will have no offset? E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

class X{

    int a;
    int b;
};

class I{};

class J{};

class Y : public I, public X,  public J{};

int main(){

    Y* y = new Y();
    X* x = y;
    I* i = y;
    J* j = y;

    std::cout << sizeof(Y) << std::endl 
                  << y << std::endl 
                  << x << std::endl 
                  << i << std::endl 
                  << j << std::endl;
}
```

Here, `Y` is the class with `X` being the only real base class. The output of the program (when compiled on linux with g++4.6) is as follows:

> 8
>
> 0x233f010
>
> 0x233f010
>
> 0x233f010
>
> 0x233f010

As I concluded, there is no pointer adjustment. But is this implementation specific or can I rely on it. I.e., if I receive an object of type `I` (and I know only these classes exist), can I use a `reinterpret_cast` to cast it to `X`?

My hopes are that that I could rely on it because the spec says that the size of an object must at least be a byte. Therefore, the compiler cannot choose another layout. If it would layout `I` and `J` behind the members of `X`, then their size would be zero (because they have no members). Therefore, the only reasonable choice is to align all super classes without offset.

Am I correct or am I playing with the fire if I use reinterpret_cast from `I` to `X` here?

Comment: Memory layout of inheritance, single or multiple, empty bases or not, is not defined.

Comment: I'd say you're playing with fire, because you're trying to make a very strange construct which will certainly cause pain and misery to anyone who has to understand it in future, even if it doesn't break when you upgrade your compiler!

Comment: luckily, your statements are no longer correct in C++11, see the answer :)

Comment: @n.m. it is implementation *defined*. The implementation is required to document it, so it is *defined*, just not in the standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++11 the compiler is required to use the Empty Base-class Optimization for *standard layout* types. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10789707/981959

For your specific example all the types are standard layout classes and don't have common base classes or members (see below) so you can rely on that behaviour **in C++11**  (and in practice, I think many compilers already followed that rule, certainly G++ did, and others following the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://sourcery.mentor.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html).)

A caveat: make sure you don't have any base classes of the same type, because they must be at distinct addresses, e.g.

```
struct I {};

struct J : I {};
struct K : I { };

struct X { int i; };

struct Y : J, K, X { };

#include <iostream>

Y y;

int main()
{
  std::cout << &y << ' ' << &y.i << ' ' << (X*)&y << ' ' << (I*)(J*)&y << ' ' << (I*)(K*)&y << '\n';

}
```

prints:

```
0x600d60 0x600d60 0x600d60 0x600d60 0x600d61
```

For the type `Y` only one of the `I` bases can be at offset zero, so although the `X` sub-object is at offset zero (i.e. `offsetof(Y, i)` is zero) and one of the `I` bases is at the same address, but the other `I` base is (at least with G++ and Clang++) one byte into the object, so if you got an `I*` you couldn't `reinterpret_cast` to `X*` because you wouldn't know *which* `I` sub-object it pointed to, the `I` at offset 0 or the `I` at offset 1.

It's OK for the compiler to put the second `I` sub-object at offset 1 (i.e. *inside* the `int`) because `I` has no non-static data members, so you can't actually dereference or access anything at that address, only get a pointer to the object at that address.  If you added non-static data members to `I` then `Y` would no longer be standard layout and would not have to use the EBO, and `offsetof(Y, i)` would no longer be zero.

Comment: yes, of course. I must ensure that the class has standard-layout. Thanks!

Comment: (Updated the example to be closer to your original). In my example `Y` _is_ standard layout, but it wouldn't be safe to `reinterpret_cast` an `I*` to `J*`, `K*`, `Y*` or `X*` because you wouldn't know which `I*` it points to.

Comment: okay, so no inhertance diamonds and only standard-layout. Right like that?

Comment: At the time you wrote this answer all the types in your example were standard-layout types, but they are not anymore because of [\[class.prop\](3.5)](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop#3.5). However, if you run your code in the most recent versions of GCC and clang, **basically** [you still get the same addresses](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a44648b6f36deb4a). Could you explain how this is possible, given that pointers to `Y` and `J` and pointers to `Y` and `K` are no longer [pointer-intercovertible](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#def:pointer-interconvertible)?

Comment: @Belloc the rules of the Itanium ABI are not specified in terms of standard-layout or pointer-interconvertibility, so the required layout does not change when the definition of standard-layout changes. Everything in the last two paragraphs ("For the type `Y`..." and "It's OK for the compiler to put ...") is still true in C++20. Replace "standard layout" with "POD for the purposes of layout" if you prefer.