# Empty derived optimization

Tags: c++, class, optimization, memory-management, compiler-optimization

Most C++ programmers know about the empty base class optimazation as a [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325144/when-do-programmers-use-empty-base-optimization-ebo)/[idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization). **What happens with empty child classes?** For example

```
class EmptyBase {
    int i;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : T { 
};

std::cout << sizeof(Derived<EmptyBase>); // Is there a standard verdic on this?
```

Similarly to the EBO there should be an EDO stating that **since a derived class doesn't provide any more members, nor introduces any virtual ones to its parametrizing type**, it should not require more memory. Considering the various situations in which something like that might apper (multiple inheritance, single inheritance ...) :

- Is such an optimization standard/possible?
- If yes, **what are the mechanics of such an optimization**, are they similar to [EBO's](https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=319)?

Note: Using class templates that derive from their parameterizing types is fairly typical. The topic is about space wasting in such situations

Comment: By the way, "EBO" is a misnomer. I'd call it "base class layout optimization" or so, since it can apply nontrivially also to nonempty classes.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10788823/596781).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard does not contain an "empty base class" case per se. Rather, it says (cf. 1.8):

> [A] most derived object shall have a non-zero size and shall occupy one or more
>   bytes of storage. Base class subobjects may have zero size.

And:

> Unless an object is [...] a base class subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. Two objects [...] may have the same address if one is a subobject of the other, or if at least one is a base class subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they shall have distinct addresses.

And (Clause 9):

> Complete objects and member subobjects of class type shall have nonzero size. Footnote:  Base class subobjects are not so constrained.

This never says that only empty bases are amenable to any kind of layout change and leaves ample room for "squeezing" the layout: for example:

```
struct A {}; struct B : A { int x; };             // "equivalent" to { int }

struct X { int a; }; struct Y : X {};             // "equivalent" to { int }
```

Consider `B b;` and `Y y;`. it is possible that the address of `b`, that of the `A`-subobject of `b` (i.e. `&static_cast<A&>(b)`) and that of `b.x` are the same, and similarly that the address of `y`, the `X`-suboject of `y`, and the address of `y.a` are the same.

The only thing that does not work is this:

```
struct S {}; struct T { S s; };                   // "equivalent" to { char }
```

By `"equivalent"` I mean the most sensible, space-saving implementation.

A more interesting case is the following:

```
struct Foo { int x; char a; };                    // { int, char, char[3] }

struct Bar : Foo { short q; };                    // { int, char, char, short }
```

This example assumes `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(short) == 2`. We have `sizeof(Foo) == 8` for alignment reasons, but `sizeof(Bar)` is also `8` despite having more data members.

---

Another relevant part of the standard is 9.2/13:

> Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11). Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1).

Finally, 9.2/10 says that standard-layout classes have no padding at the beginning, so that their address equals the address of their "initial member". Since standard-layout requires that all bases either be empty, or that the most-derived class itself have no data members, this means that standard-layout classes *must* employ a kind of "empty base" optimization, and the initial part of the layout of my `B` and `Y` above is actually mandatory.

Comment: +1 [but Visual C++ users beware](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701469/why-empty-base-class-optimization-is-not-working)