# Size of base class inside derived class

Tags: c++

Suppose I have class with no data:

```
struct Empty {
  /*some methods here*/
};
```

And a derived class

```
struct Derived: Empty {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c;
  ....
}__attribute__((packed));`
```

Objects of Empty class have size = 1. Empty part of derived class usually has 0 size. As I understand compiler see that base Empty class has no data so it can optimize size of Empty in case it is "inside" Derived but it is not required to do it by the standard.

So  the question is:

Can I somehow determine at compile time that Empty part of Derived class doesn't really occupy memory.

I understand that I can do check like `sizeof(Derived) = sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) ...` But It is too verbose and there are several classes like Derived. Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Note that a member or base class can occupy memory without adding to the footprint of the derived class (by using space lost to padding). Also note that `sizeof` on a struct can be less or more than the sum of the `sizeof` of it's member and bases.

Comment: I'm going to use these Derived classes to represent some network data. So all such Derived classes will have packed attribute. Also I'm going to  inherit from some template class to implement  Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. So that all derived classes will have some common functionality. However I don't want that this inheritance affects the layout of Derived classes.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`std::is_empty`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_empty) to make sure that the class you're inheriting from is zero-sized:

```
static_assert(std::is_empty<Empty>{});
```

If it is, [*empty base optimization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is [guaranteed to take place for *standard-layout classes*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788823/is-the-empty-base-class-optimization-now-a-mandatory-optimization-at-least-for).

---

> I understand that I can do check like `sizeof(Derived) = sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) ...` But It is too verbose. Is there more elegant solution?

This does not work properly because you need to take padding into account and eventual attributes such as `packed`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know this optimization is guaranteed.

Comment: The standard does not guarantee this optimisation.   It is pretty common in practice though with real-world compilers.

Comment: @Peter: [it is guaranteed for *standard-layout* classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788823/is-the-empty-base-class-optimization-now-a-mandatory-optimization-at-least-for). I'll clarify my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use more "old" (**before** C++11) macro - [offsetof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof):

```
struct Empty {};
struct NonEmpty {
  int a;
};
struct Derived1: Empty {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c;
};
struct Derived2: NonEmpty {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c;
};
static_assert(offsetof(Derived1,a) == 0,"");
static_assert(offsetof(Derived2,a) != 0,"");
```

You can use this macro to check order of your member variables too:

```
static_assert(offsetof(Derived,a) < offsetof(Derived,b),"");
static_assert(offsetof(Derived,b) < offsetof(Derived,c),"");
```

But do not forget - offsetof has the same limitation:

> If type is not a standard layout type, the behavior is undefined.
>   If member is a static member or a member function, the behavior is undefined.